Recursive way of finding parent and children for each row
I have a table with client_id and parent_clientid. Each client can be a parent and can contain multiple children. I would like to know, for each row, how to get the associated parent and children in a concatenated string (like in the example). I do not want to run the query based on client id or primary client id. The expected result string should list the presence of this clientid wherever it is present. Is it possible?



client_id
primary_client_id
Expected result




1
NULL
1,10,11,57,65


2
NULL
2,3,4,6,56


3
2
2,4,6,56


4
2
2,3,6,56


6
2
2,3,4,56


7
NULL
7,8,9,58,59


8
7
7,9,58,59


9
7
7,8,58,59


10
1
1,11,57,65


11
1
1,10,57,65


48
NULL
48,49,50,52


49
48
48,50,52


50
48
48,49,52


51
NULL
51


52
48
48,49,50


53
NULL
53


54
NULL
54


55
NULL
55


56
2
2,3,4,6


57
1
1,10,11,65


58
7
7,8,9,59


59
7
7,8,9,58


60
NULL
60


61
NULL
61


62
NULL
62


63
NULL
63


64
NULL
64


65
1
1,10,11,57,65



enter image description here
with recursive myCTE (root_id, client_id, firstname, lastname, primary_client_id) as (
    # the most basic level, we need to remember the root id and name
    select client_id as root_id,
           client_id,
           firstname,
           lastname,
           primary_client_id
    from clients
    union all
    select mC.root_id,
           cl.client_id,
           mC.firstname,
           mC.lastname,
           cl.primary_client_id
    from clients cl
    inner join myCTE mC on cl.primary_client_id = mC.client_id
    
)
select * from (
select root_id, group_concat(client_id order by client_id ASC) as simple_skus
from myCTE
group by root_id
) t1 


Expected result It is extremely strange. For some rows you include client_id into expected result but for some another you skip it. For some rows you include not only parents/childs but also the neighbors.. It seems that your sample is not accurate simply - either fix it or explain the above differences.

Hi Akina, the expected result should have a concatenated string of the client_id, primary_client_id and the other children of the same parent.

Here's the thing, without a starting point like a client_id, crafting a query to fetch the chains for every record in the table will likely be a performance nightmare. The closest I can think of is to get all the possible 'family trees' and have those concatenated together. The catch here is you'd get each client listed out multiple times (in any/each group they belong to). Unfortunately, databases just aren't built to handle that kind of recursive relationship tracing in a super-efficient way.

With my recursive CTE query I'm able to get the children of the parent. However what is challenging is that, for every row, i want to do this. I want to know who is in this "team" (including parent and other children).
